# How can I tell which Unix shell I am using?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Is there an easy way by which I can tell which type of Unix shell I am in?

A command that shows whether I am in a Bash, [C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell), [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell) (`ksh`), [tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh), or [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`)?

E.g.,

`whatshellisthis`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Try:

```
echo $0
```

This often works across a range of shells.

Comment: Doesn't work with fish

Comment: @rominf: with `fish` just type `$` and then `tab`. You'll see a bunch of `$__fish` and `$fish` variables defined

Comment: This also doesn't work from within a sourced file.

Answer (score 22):

#### Mac

```
ps

  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  223 ttys000    0:00.33 -bash
```

#### [OpenBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD)

```
ps

  PID TT  STAT       TIME COMMAND
20038 p0  Ss      0:00.01 -ksh (ksh)
22251 p0  R+      0:00.00 ps
```

Or just `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: I think `$SHELL` is the default shell for the system (or user), which is usually (but not necessarily) the shell that is actually being used at any given moment.

Answer (score 12):

The `echo $SHELL` command will give you your shell name relative to root.

Comment: SHELL is not guaranteed to be set. For instance, my login shell is bash, but is I run /bin/sh at the command line, SHELL is still /bin/bash even though /bin/sh ls dash.

Comment: $SHELL is the login shell. If your login shell is bash and you start tcsh, then $SHELL will still be bash even tough the shell you are running is tcsh.

Comment: check out  # ps -p $$ | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'

Answer (score 8):

Every shell I know of sets the $ variable ($$) to its pid.  So...

```
ps | grep $$
```

Comment: Fish is the exception. You need to use %self

Comment: Sometimes I feel like fish should not be counted among "unix shells".
We're very comfortable in our pile of spaghetti, please don't straighten all the noodles.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the OS X terminal, then the shell is specified in the Terminal's title bar when you launch it - like so:  `Terminal - ShellName - 80x24`

Comment: I think this is this correct answer.