# "echo -n" prints "-n"

Tags: sh

I have a problem with `echo` in my script:

```
echo -n "Some string..."
```

prints

```
-n Some string...
```

and moves to the next line. In the console it's working correcly without newline:

```
Some string...
```

Comment: Which bourne shell implementation are you using? If I run `bash` in bourne shell mode, it works fine here. Also, it's somewhat unlikely you're really using a bourne shell as your interactive shell, no?

Comment: on Ubuntu: `echo -ne "text without new line: "; echo "some text";`

Comment: I know this is very old, but this works for me in Windows 10, to add a period without a newline:  echo | set /p="."

Comment: On MacOS (Monterey), I hit this on a script with `#!/usr/bin/env sh` at the top.  Very curious since sh and bash both claim they are "GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin21)".  But I proved it:  `sh -c "echo -n"` prints `-n` whereas `bash -c "echo -n"` does not.

Answer (score 677, accepted):

There are multiple versions of the `echo` command, with different behaviors. It's often built into the shell. If it isn't, `echo` will typically invoke `/bin/echo` or `/usr/bin/echo`, which itself can be from any of a number of implementations.

Apparently the shell used for your script uses a version that doesn't recognize `-n`.

The `printf` command has much more consistent behavior. `echo` is fine for simple things like `echo hello`, but I suggest using `printf` for anything more complicated.

What system are you on, and what shell does your script use?

Comment: By starting with the line `#!/bin/bash` it worked. Normally I'm working with bash.

Comment: I wish there was a Windows equivalent in CMD :( As far as I can see, there isn't, just workarounds to achieve the same behavior.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: Perhaps there's a Windows version of the `printf` command.

Comment: I wish. `echo` always adds newlines... The workaround is jenky at best.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeckO Of course it's been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290074/bash-printf-equivalent-for-command-prompt

Comment: printf doing better than echo.

Comment: `printf` shows `%` (`\0`) after each print, how can I supress it

Comment: @alper Impossible to tell without knowing what arguments you passed to `printf`. Perhaps you should post a new question.

Comment: I was in zsh, and I just passed a  string. `printf hello` but output is `hello%`

Comment: @alper The `%` is your shell prompt. Try this, and watch carefully: `printf hello; sleep 5`

Comment: It's not necessarily the prompt; `zsh` has an option to display a particular character to indicate the absence of a newline, so that the prompt can be displayed on the following line in every case without confusion.

Comment: @chepner And if he had used that option, he wouldn't have seen `hello%`. If it's not the prompt, what else could it be? (BTW, what is that option?)

Comment: @KeithThompson. `PROMPT_SP` controls whether a partial line is preserved; `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` lets you change what `PROMPT_SP` displays, but the default is `%` for ordinary users and `#` for root users. (So it's related in some way to the prompt, but it's not just the prompt being displayed immediately after the output.)

Answer (score 186):

`bash` has a "built-in" command called "echo":

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

Additionally, there is an "echo" command that is a proper executable (that is, the shell forks and execs `/bin/echo`, as opposed to interpreting `echo` and executing it):

```
$ ls -l /bin/echo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22856 Jul 21  2011 /bin/echo
```

The behavior of either `echo`'s with respect to `\c` and `-n` varies.  Your best bet is to use `printf`, which is available on four different *NIX flavors that I looked at:

```
$ printf "a line without trailing linefeed"
$ printf "a line with trailing linefeed\n"
```

Comment: This is an important answer, because it helps to distinguish between echo as a command vs echo as an executable, which is not necessarily obvious when scripting. This means that if you really wanted to get the default behavior of the echo that you're used to, you can make sure you use the executable by using `/bin/echo -n` to get the no-newline display. `printf` may be a better option, but if you're used to using echo, you can still get the functionality you're expecting that way.

Comment: On MacOS `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` are both bash (and thus use the builtin), but only the former supports the `-n` option.  I found a nice explanation of that at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410266/157202 ... `sh` runs in POSIX compatibility mode.

Answer (score 103):

Try with

```
echo -e "Some string...\c"
```

It works for me as expected (as I understood from your question).

Note that I got this information from the `man` page. The `man` page also notes the shell may have its own version of `echo`, and I am not sure if `bash` has its own version.

Comment: +1 for hinting me to the right direction, though echo that does not recognise -ne option probably doesn't recognise -e (nor need) option either so you probably want to just say `echo "some string...\c"` instead. If however you need to support multiple bash variants with wildly differing echo commands you probably are better of using printf or you need to be checking the echo commands capabilities with something like `[ -n "$( echo -e )" ] && echo "sh stuff\c" || echo -e "bash stuff\c"` (at least bash supports \c as well, so no need to use the -n option, but you need the -e for bash)

Comment: To me, this does exactly what -n does in OP's case: outputs literal -e. I guess printf is indeed more consistent

Comment: -e will not work in a posix shell script, it will be output to the screen instead.

Comment: `-e` is not needed in `zsh`. `-n` (no new line) works. Why not use `zsh` and leave the other shells?

Answer (score 13):

To achieve this there are basically two methods which I frequently use:

**1.** Using the ***cursor*** escape character (`\c`)  with `echo -e`

*Example* :

```
for i in {0..10..2}; do
  echo -e "$i \c"              
done
# 0 2 4 6 8 10
```

- `-e` flag enables the **E**scape characters in the string.
- `\c` brings the **C**ursor back to the current line.

***OR***

**2.** Using the `printf` command

*Example*:

```
for ((i = 0; i < 5; ++i)); do
  printf "$i "
done
# 0 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use *echo* inside an *if* with other commands, like "read", it might ignore the setting and it will jump to a new line anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the [most popular Linux distribution](https://www.zdnet.com/article/whats-the-most-popular-linux-of-them-all/), [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) and its Bash:

1. Check which shell are you using. Mostly the below works, else [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349370/how-to-tell-which-unix-shell-i-am-using):

   `echo $0`
2. If above prints `bash`, then the below will work:

   `printf "hello with no new line printed at end"`

   Or

   `echo -n "hello with no new line printed at end"`

Answer (score 2):

I believe right now your output prints as below

```sh
~ echo -e "String1\nString2"
String1
String2
```

You can use [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) to get multiline standard output into same line.

```
 ~ echo -e "String1\nString2" | xargs
String1 String2

 ~
```

Answer (score 2):

```
enable -n echo
echo -n "Some string..."
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What version of Bash was it tried on? On what operating system (incl. e.g. Linux distribution and version)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60703359/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

Note that */usr/bin/echo* and */bin/echo* on [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX) don't support any arguments, so neither *-n* nor *-e* work if using sh or [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell) (`ksh`) shells.

*[C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell)* and [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) have their own built-in *echo* which supports *-n*. 
This is relevant, because a lot of shell scripts explicitly use *sh* or KornShell.

AIX does have */usr/bin/printf*, so as suggested in some earlier answers,

```
$ printf "whatever"
```

is equivalent to `echo -n "whatever"` where *-n* is supported.

Answer (score 0):

When you go and write your shell script, always use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the first line.

This shell doesn't omit or manipulate escape sequences.

Example:

```
echo "This is first \\n line"
```

prints

```
This is first \n line.
```

Comment: An explanation for `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is in *[What is the difference between "#!/usr/bin/env bash" and "#!/usr/bin/bash"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365130/)*.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in IBM [z/OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z/OS), so I used ***print*** instead of ***echo***, and it worked.

```
print -n "Some string ...."
```

*[print — Return arguments from the shell](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=descriptions-print-return-arguments-from-shell)*