# How to rename last N commits messages in git?

Tags: git

I have 30 commits and I want to add "Bug XXXXXXX" at the beginning of all the messages, can I do this in a single action/command?

I'm trying to avoid squashing them.

Comment: did you try [git ammend](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html) not sure if that will let you do multiple commits tho

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `git rebase -i HEAD~<N>` where N is the number of commits to go back, and `-i` will make it interactive, ie it will open in vim or whatever your default editor is. See [Scott Chacon's Book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages). Then you can change the commit message.

If you need it automated, then you may need to try [filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html#The-Nuclear-Option%3a-filter-branch):

> another history-rewriting option that you can use if you need to
>   rewrite a larger number of commits in some scriptable way

In this case you would use:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter <command>
```

See [man git-filter-branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)

Here is the example given in the manual to append "Acked-by" to a range of commits. You can change it to "BUG XXXXXXX"

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter '
    echo "Bug XXXXXXX: \c"
    && cat
    ' HEAD~<N>..HEAD
```

where N is the number of commits to go back and append "BUG XXXXXXX"

Comment: I would like to avoid stopping after each commit I want to modify and change the message...

Comment: here's a [list of SO's recent filter branch questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-filter-branch)

Comment: Nice solution! Just one thing before setting this answer as solution, the messages are now: "Bug XXXX: \n <old message>", how can I leave the whole new message in one line? Thanks!

Comment: Try `echo -n "Bug XXXX: " && cat` to avoid the trailing newline. Does that work?

Comment: Nope...it prints: "-n Bug XXXX: \n <old message>". Weird, because only Bug XXX is between "".

Comment: "git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'echo "Bug XXXXXXX: \c" && cat' HEAD~N..HEAD" is the final answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be better not to depend on either of the following:

```
echo -n "Bug XXXXXXX: "

echo "Bug XXXXXXX: \c"
```

The behavior of echo is dependent on which version of echo is being used. See the linked stackoverflow question below:

['echo' without newline in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193466/echo-without-newline-in-a-shell-script)

A better solution might be:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter '
    printf "%s" "Bug XXXXXXX: "
    && cat
    ' HEAD~<N>..HEAD
```