# Read / Echo Environmental Variable as Literal

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

Very basic, or so I thought. I've got this string in a command prompt:

```
C:\>echo "start C:\Users\%USERNAME%\My Documents" >> Test.txt
```

I've tried %%USERNAME%%, '%USERNAME%', '%'USERNAME'%', and many other ways. The batch output always resolves the environmental variable rather than writing it as a literal string of text. Is it possible to make sure it reads this as a literal string of text and not the environment variable it resolves to?

Comment: are you asking how to write the string "start C:\Users\%USERNAME%\My Documents" to a text document "test.txt"?

Comment: Yes, without it resolving the environmental variable %USERNAME% and writing it exactly how you stated.

Comment: From you tag its a batch file correct? "echo "start C:\Users\%USERNAME%\My Documents" >> Test.txt" works both from the command line and as a batch file.What problem are you having?Where do you want the file to be written by the way?in the C: directory?

Comment: without resolving username to another value. they want to take the literal string %username% and put it in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo start ^"^" ^"C:\Users\^%username^%\my documents^" >> test.txt
```

this should work.

Answer (score 2):

This command works differently at the command line Vs a batch file.  In a batch file this works:

```
@echo off
echo start "" "C:\Users\%%username%%\my documents" >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea why your method doesn't work (I couldn't make it work either), but if you do the echo in two parts like this:

```
echo.|set /P="start C:\Users\%" >> Test.txt
echo USERNAME%\My Documents >> Test.txt
```

Then it should work.  The first line is something I found here: ['echo' without newline in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193466/shell-script-echo-without-newline)

The docs do say that %% should put a literal % in, but apparently the rule to put %USERNAME% has a higher precedence.

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.