# Unwanted line break in C

Tags: c, linux, printf, newline, fgets

I have created a little script in C which displays text in a Linux console, but I found one problem - the script adds a line break at the end of text. I have no idea why, normally I should get line break after `/n`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    char txt[100];
    printf("Insert a text: ");
    fgets(txt, 100, stdin);
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "echo '%s'", txt);
    system(buf);
}
```

The structure of the code has to stay the same. I need to use system function and `snprintf()`.

I want to make a few things clear. Right when I'm running this script the output looks like this:

```
root@test:/home# ./app
Insert a text: Hello
Hello

root@test:/home#
```

How can I remove this newline after `Hello`?

Comment: LineBreak is `\n` not `/n`

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193466/shell-script-echo-without-newline) for removing newlines from echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets` consumes the `\n` character in the buffer which you press after entering data. Just add

```
txt[strcspn(txt,"\n")] = 0;
```

just after the `fgets` to replace the `\n` character at the end of `txt` with a NUL-terminator. The [`strcspn` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/), in your case, counts the number of characters in `txt` until a `\n` character. If no newline character is found, then it returns the length of `txt`(`strlen(txt)`).

BTW, you need to include `string.h` if you want to use this function:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: I'm getting : app.c: In function ‘main’:
app.c:9:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcspn’ [enabled by default]
 txt[strcspn(txt,"\n")] = 0;
     ^

Comment: Oh. I forgot to mention that you need to include `string.h` for using this function.

Comment: THANK YOU !! Everything is working now how it should be!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is related with how `fgets()` behave. As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

> `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);`
>
> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than `size` characters from `stream` and stores them into the buffer pointed to by `s`. Reading stops after an `EOF` or a `newline`. If a `newline` is read, it is stored into the buffer.

So, it reads and stores the trailing `\n` (newline) generated by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after the input into `txt`. If you don't want that `\n` to be present in `txt`, you need to remove that from the input buffer manually before printing the contents of `txt`.

You can use `strchr()` or `strcspn()` to find out the *possible* `\n` and replace that with `\0` (`null`) to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm not looking for breakdown - I want to remove it !

Comment: @Matt I got your question wrong. Hope it is fine now.