# Where is the extra carriage return coming from?

Tags: c

I am attempting to learn c programming.

I have written this small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    // variable declarations
    long nc;
    char ch;

    // initialize variables
    nc = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        printf("%d\t%c\n", ch, ch);
        ++nc;
    }

    printf("Number of characters typed: %ld\n", nc);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and I created a small text file like so:

```
echo "abcdef" > text.txt
```

When I run this program like so:

```
./countchar < text.txt
```

I get the following output:

```
97      a
98      b
99      c
100     d
101     e
102     f
10

Number of characters typed: 7
```

My question is what the 10 represents in this case (linefeed?) and why it appears as a seventh character when I have run this program using redirection.

Comment: Did you open the text file in an editor? Did you read the manpage of `echo`? Did you do any effort to find the reason yourself? And ASCII `10` is not carriage return, but line feed.

Comment: Try `echo -n "abcdef" > text.txt` if you are on Linux.

Comment: no i did not open it in an editor. I did exactly and only what i typed above.  I did not read the manpage of echo as I am a complete, utter beginner working from a book.  But i have read it now, thank you for the tip olaf, and have figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `echo "abcdef"`, you get a line feed at the end. That's just how `echo` works by default. So, your text file contains 7 characters: `abcdef\n`.

Your c program works correctly and shows the number `10` (ASCII value of `\n`) and a literal line feed.

On most systems ([but not all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11193533/2057919)), you can do `echo -n "abcdef"` to avoid the new line. Alternatively (and more portably), use `printf` instead of `echo` if you care about the new line character.

Comment: More *portably*, not more reliably. `echo -n` is perfectly reliable on systems that support it.