# How can I 'echo' out things without a newline?

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
for x in "${array[@]}"
do
  echo "$x"
done
```

The results are something like this (I sort these later in some cases):

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is there a way to print it as `1 2 3 4 5` instead? Without adding a newline every time?

Comment: That would be slightly trickier to sort.

Comment: aside: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: ...also, "tried `printf`" doesn't show *how* you tried using `printf`. Details matter. :)

Comment: `array=( 1 2 3 4 5 ); printf '%s ' "${array[@]}"; echo` -- prints a single line with `1 2 3 4 5 ` in its contents.

Comment: ...re: your edit, also include how you're populating the array. I'm guessing you're using `readarray` or `mapfile` without `-t`, which is putting literal newlines in your data.

Comment: ...and really, if you're using `readarray` or `mapfile`, why not sort your data on the input side instead of the output side? `readarray -t array < <(sort input.txt)`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah I think I am populating with new lines. Thanks. I'll have to find another approach.

Comment: ...you could also add `declare -p array` and its output to your question, which will give you a line that reproduces the data at hand. Assuming that that data is what you actually *want*, we could then give you a fix that works with it, such as `printf '%s ' "${array[@]%$'\n'}"` (if my guess re: trailing newlines is correct).

Comment: actually, just preprocessing with `array=( "${array[@]%$'\n'}" )` will do, if it's only trailing, UNIX-style newlines that are an issue.

Comment: ...btw, this is part of why we ask for questions to contain a minimal, **complete, verifiable** example -- to make this complete and verifiable it would have needed to include actual values for the array that reproduced the issue as part of the question, which would have meant we wouldn't have been fumbling around before figuring out your actual problem; see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought that's what I was doing...

Comment: if you'd had `array=( 1 2 3 4 5 )` or an equivalent which actually produced your bug, then you would have been. That's part of why *testing* your example in a clean environment (http://ideone.com/ is ideal, since that way you *know* you aren't relying on something just on your machine) before hitting "post" is good practice.

Comment: The canonical is *["echo -n" prints "-n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193466/)*.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Yes. Use the `-n` option:

```
echo -n "$x"
```

From `help echo`:

> -n do not append a newline

This would strips off the last newline too, so if you want you can add a final newline after the loop:

```
for ...; do ...; done; echo
```

---

**Note:**

This is not portable among various implementations of `echo` builtin/external executable. The portable way would be to use `printf` instead:

```
printf '%s' "$x"
```

Comment: thanks it just prints out the '-n' instead before each number

Comment: Any reason to put the `echo` approach before the portable one?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As OP was using `echo` already, so thought about going with that first..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks I tried the edit. Still the same thing...

Comment: @ricky162, again, **details matter**. Have to see *how* you tried it to know how it failed. Now, `printf '%s' "$x"` has its own problems, inasmuch as it doesn't put any spaces between the items (so it would emit `12345`, not `1 2 3 4 5`), but it certainly doesn't print any newlines unless the array itself contains newline literals.

Comment: @ricky162, ...if you're seeing behavior other than that, then you necessarily have other problems -- such as data that doesn't represent what you put in the question; content with newline literals embedded in the array body, for instance.

Comment: @ricky162 did you run the script with sh instead of bash? with bash it works as expected, with sh it prints literal -n

Answer (score 10):

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | sort | tr '\n' ' '
```

`printf '%s\n'` -- more robust than `echo` and you want the newlines here for `sort`'s sake
`"${array[@]}"` -- quotes unnecessary for your particular array, but good practice as you don't generally want word-spliting and glob expansions there

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a *for* loop to sort numbers from an array.

Use process substitution like this:

```
sort <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}")
```

To remove new lines, use:

```
sort <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}") | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 4):

If, for whatever reason, `-n` doesn't fix this for you, you can also add `\c` to the end of the thing to be echo'd:

```sh
echo "$x\c"
```

Comment: This is just as poorly portable as `echo -n`, and less widely supported.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the `-n` in some cases and it did not work. This was the only way I could make it work.

Comment: @tripleee actually, echo -n is NOT portable at all: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/echo/info - in short: echo -n will actually print -n on some systems, specifically on MacOS "sh". this answer is a valid option.

Comment: @lzap That's precisely what I was saying. Both of these should be avoided in favor of the properly portable - as well as vastly more versatile - `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it this way:

```sh
array=(1 2 3 4 5)
echo "${array[@]}"
```