# PHPSeclib additional line breaks using write

Tags: php, phpseclib

I'm getting close to the point of simply moving this back to PERL for a specific use case of editing files via SSH.  It seems no matter what I do, additional line breaks are being placed in the file.  Sample variable has the following:

```
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = US
```

Using the following command, I get the output below

```
$ssh->write("echo '$file' > /directory/test.txt\n");
```

Resulting in:

```
req_extensions = v3_req

prompt = no

[req_distinguished_name]

C = US
```

Edit adding relevant debug log:

```
<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0022, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0005, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:63                       ........c

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0005, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:68                       ........h

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0003, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0005, network: 0.0003s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0004, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:27                       ........'

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:72                       ........r

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0003, network: 0.0002s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:71                       ........q

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:5f                       ........_

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0007, network: 0.0006s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:78                       ........x

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0003, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:74                       ........t

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0003, network: 0.0002s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6e                       ........n

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:73                       ........s

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:69                       ........i

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0005, network: 0.0002s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0005, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6e                       ........n

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:73                       ........s

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0004, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:3d                       ........=

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:76                       ........v

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:33                       ........3

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:5f                       ........_

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:72                       ........r

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:71                       ........q

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:02:0d:0a                    ..........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:02:3e:20                    ........> 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0005, network: 0.0004s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:02:0d:0a                    ..........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:02:3e:20                    ........> 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:70                       ........p

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:72                       ........r

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6d                       ........m

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:70                       ........p

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:74                       ........t

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:3d                       ........=

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0002s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6e                       ........n

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0002s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:02:0d:0a                    ..........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:02:3e:20                    ........> 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:02:0d:0a                    ..........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:02:3e:20                    ........>
```

TIA

Comment: You want to remove new line or want to add new line?

Comment: I don't want the additional line breaks that aren't actually in my string.

Comment: Would need to see the hex for that string variable I think? CR and LF perhaps?

Comment: You added `\n` in the end of that command. Remove that and it will remove the newline.

Your command can be `$ssh->write("echo '$file' > /directory/test.txt");`

Comment: ^ Wondered about that too.  Wouldn't that just get you `test.txtn`?

Comment: @ShahariaAzam - the \n was just to force carriage return.  Removing it doesn't make any difference - I still get the "test.txt" file with unintended line breaks compared with the string.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `-n` and it should fix that.

`$ssh->write("echo -n '$file' > /directory/test.txt\n");`

`-n`  tell not to append a new line.

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: According to http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/echoh.html `echo` man page. `-n` should solve this. Though it worked for me. See my gist on https://gist.github.com/shahariaazam/d1d3b2c2af76ca2124eeecca814bc947

Comment: Also I found the similar question's solutions here at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021361/1431786

Comment: Right - echo isn't the problem here, it's whatever phpseclib is doing with the "write" method that I believe to be the issue.  I can take the same text and echo no problem via a native shell.

Comment: You can use `exec()` method for that if the `write` method have any problem. Also what's the OS of your remote server?

Comment: The server I'm running the commands on is FreeBSD, no matter what I do with `exec()`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Would still like to know what `$file` is. You are certain the extra line breaks are not there?

Comment: Of course - no additional line breaks in $file.  It's as I wrote at the start.

Comment: I'll... I suppose... I guess I'll take your word for it :) Do wonder though about the 4 lines shown between the `q` and `p` in the debug output you shared.

Comment: Sorry to prolong this - just to add,`exec()` does actually put it in correctly, but my problem is I have an @ symbol in part of the text which is why `exec()` doesn't work for me.  I can always use sed to fix this I suppose, was just hoping for a better way.

Comment: Too beat the horse further.. Why not use `put`?

Comment: @ficuscr - I wanted to chain additional commands, I'm going that route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `write()` was sending additional line breaks.  I'm sure if I went line by line and appended to the file that would have worked.  In the end, I simply used `SFTP::put()` which allowed me to place the `@` that which wouldn't work with `SSH::exec()`.  Thanks for all the input - it's a little different method than I would have liked, but it works.