# base64 gives incorrect result

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encoding, vnc

Because I am setting up vnc server, I need to convert string to base64 to setup password. ([How to setup vnc password](https://askubuntu.com/a/12195)

Say, if I want my password to be `qwerty`, I have to place the encoded string into the password into conf file.

I see there is a `base64` utility in Ubuntu. [man base64](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64). `echo qwerty | base64` gives `cXdlcnR5Cg==`. But this doesn't work.

But if I use the [online base 64 tool](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp). `qwerty` is encoded to `cXdlcnR5`. This string WILL WORK.

Question: why the two base64 encode gives different result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does base64 encoding require padding if the input length is not divisible by 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4080988/608639), [How to echo out things without a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38021348/608639), etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

echo adds a '\n' ; try echo -n

```
$ echo -n qwerty | base64 
cXdlcnR5
```