# How do I reconfigure my Mac to get bash script to use echo like it used to?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

Not a Mac guy here.

Many months ago I wrote the following command in a bash script on a Mac.

```
export AUTH=$(echo -n "$USER_ID:$SVC_KEY" | base64)
```

It worked as you would expect, the base64 of "value_of_USER_ID:value_of_SVC_KEY". Months later I run it and the output is the base64 of "-n value_of_USER_ID:value_of_SVC_KEY".

InB4 yes, it took me a while to figure out that this was the problem :-)

**What setting changed to cause the "-n " to be included? How do I change it back?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may have changed your shell from `bash` to `sh`. In `sh` the way to echo without a newline is to end it with `\c`:

```
export AUTH=$(echo "$USER_ID:$SVC_KEY\c" | base64)
```

But a more portable way to print without a newline is to use `printf`:

```
export AUTH=$(printf "%s" "$USER_ID:$SVC_KEY" | base64)
```

See ['echo' without newline in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193466/echo-without-newline-in-a-shell-script)