# Cut string from file on delimiter

Tags: bash, shell

I am completely new to bash and I have a file that contains some string records, let's say

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
```

and I need to make another file that looks like this:

```
2 4 5 3 1
7 9 10 8 6
...
```

but I got this:

```
2 4 5
3 1
7 9 10
8 6
```

The problem is probably caused by the fact that there is no delimiter at the end of the line and it takes enter when printing, but I don't know how to solve this.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=file.txt
a=$(cut -d',' -f2 $FILE)
b=$(cut -d',' -f4 $FILE)
c=$(cut -d',' -f5 $FILE)
d=$(cut -d',' -f3 $FILE)
e=$(cut -d',' -f1 $FILE)


paste <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b") <(echo "$c") <(echo "$d") <(echo "$e") --delimiters ' '> new.txt
```

Comment: you should use printf instead of echo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193466/echo-without-newline-in-a-shell-script

Comment: Also, tangentially, [use lowercase for your private variables](/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and [quote them.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 5):

If your task is simply to change the field separator and reorder the fields, reading the entire file into memory is hugely inefficient. Just process one line at a time.

```
awk -F, '{ print $2, $4, $5, $3, $1 }' file.txt >new.txt
```

Awk is more suitable than bare shell script; perhaps see also [Bash while read loop extremely slow compared to cat, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I still got enter between fifth and third element.

Comment: Probably your file contains DOS line endings, too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings

Comment: With GNU awk. This works with files from Windows or Unix/Linux, if no field contains a carriage return and/or newline: `awk -F, 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n"} {print $2, $4, $5, $3, $1 }' file`

Comment: Yeah, though not having DOS line endings is probably the way to go if at all possible. I always encourage users to consider getting rid of Windows entirely.