# Is there a better way to echo without a newline in bash than using tr -d?

Tags: bash, echo, newline

I have a script that counts down from 5 to 0:

`for a in {5..0}; do echo $a | tr -d \\n; sleep 1; echo -e \\b | tr -d \\n; done`

and tacking on `tr -d` just looks redundant and not very elegant to me. Is there a way to echo on one line without having to delete the newline?

Comment: You want just `echo -n` ?

Comment: ... or the portable version `printf '%s' "$a"`

Comment: @KamilCuk You're right, my bad, sorry. Add a dupe for bash and someone with golden badge will update it

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193466/echo-without-newline-in-a-shell-script

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sorry for misleading bud

Comment: @oguzismail, np buddy, I reverted it asap I saw it, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-n` flag with `echo`:

```
for a in {5..0}; do echo -n $a; sleep 1; echo -ne \\b; done
```

Or just use `printf`:

```
for a in {5..0}; do printf $a; sleep 1; printf \\b; done
```

Note that this will show invalid numbers if counting from numbers greater or equal to `10`. You could use `\r` carriage return character and clear the line with space, for example assume maximum number of 20 digits and use left formatting and fill the line with spaces:

```
for a in {20..0}; do printf "\r%-20d" "$a"; sleep 1; done
```

With bash `COLUMNS` variable and with `*` parameter passed width specifier with `printf` you could fill the whole line with spaces:

```
for a in {20..0}; do printf "\r%-*d" "$COLUMNS" "$a"; sleep 1; done
```

Or use a ansi escape sequence to clear the line:

```
for a in {20..0}; do printf "\r\033[K%d" "$a"; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: What a sheepish way to learn about `echo -n`. Thank you very much, and for the other scripting improvements too!